# UdpClient Error 10022 An invalid argument was supplied

Tags: c#, udpclient

I need to send a packet via UDP. In my project I am getting an error on the very first line:

```
UdpClient udpClient = new UdpClient();
```

It is just a constructor I dont know why it is giving me the error:

```
An invalid argument was supplied
```

Comment: are you sure that's the offending line? I'm not...

Comment: yes yes im debugging it does not make sense to me as well i have no idea :/

Comment: perhaps your source and binaries are out of sync? Restart Visual Studio. Clean. Rebuild all.

Comment: Already done but still the same